# Compliant way for an uninstaller to remove HKCU keys of other users

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-installer, registry

I know the general answer is "No, you don't", for example [How to remove HKCU registry keys when uninstalling software?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365508/how-to-remove-hkcu-registry-keys-when-uninstalling-software). That post suggests that if you're desperate enough you can use [RegLoadKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadkeyw) to load other users' hives.

Then [How to load registry hive for all users in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325495/how-to-load-registry-hive-for-all-users-in-a-loop) claims that loading user hives is not thread safe; If you load an users' hive then that user would not be able to log in at all. Besides, loading hives is an global action which will persist even after the process calling `RegLoadKey` terminates, so you have to be especially careful about making sure the hive unloads before your program ends.

Now, why not just leave those keys as is? Sure, for keys that would only be read by your program, you absolutely can just leave them alone. Even certain keys that interact with the OS can be left without problem, like those keys in `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, where even if the path to run no longer exists at startup it will just fail silently, so the user won't notice anything. Edit: technically the user would still see a leftover entry in his Task Manager Startup tab

However, there are certain keys that can have lingering side effects, like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage, which demonstrates registering an `CLSID` to add an "OneDrive" shortcut to the navigation pane of the Explorer.

Now say I'm developing a program just like OneDrive, and when it runs on User A it registers an `CLSID` for a shortcut at his nav pane. Now admin User B runs the uninstaller. According to this "Don't touch others registry" guideline, now the shortcut shall remain in user A's nav pane, and if he wants to get rid of it the only way would be deleting those registry keys himself?

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing to HKCU, consider creating a per-user installation package instead of a per-machine package. That avoids the problem completely.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @KenWhite When did we start suggesting to post answers as comments?

Comment: I was not making a comment, I was suggesting an answer. Admittedly, the answer side steps the OP's question but that's because there isn't a good alternative. As we learned in War Games, sometimes the only solution is to not play the game. And sometimes you need to change a rule or two to find a winning solution. Per-user is the best solution in this situation.

Comment: "It's important to remember when answering questions at StackExchange sites (especially at highly technical sites like StackOverflow) that the purpose of the site isn't mainly to solve the asker's immediate problem, but to build a knowledge base of information that is useful to other people in the future." ;)

Comment: @RobMensching: This space is for answers. In your own words, *this answer side steps the OP's question*, which means it doesn't actually answer it. The way to *build a knowledge base* is to first answer the question, and then also suggest a better solution or method. Also, note that I didn't downvote your post - I just don't agree that it answers the question asked.

Comment: To be clear about my objection, the question clearly asks *how to remove*, and your answer says *don't put it there in the first place*, which does not solve the OP's current problem at all.

Comment: @IInspectable: It's not an answer. The question is *how to remove*, and the (should be a comment instead) post says *don't put it there in the first place, which does not answer the question asked. It's very good advice going forward, but it does not answer the question asked or solve the OP's immediate problem, which is removal of a registry entry.

Comment: @KenWhite *"the question clearly asks how to remove, and your answer says don't put it there in the first place"* - Not at all. An installer can use HKCU just fine. That's not the issue. This answer just says to not use a per-machine uninstaller for a per-user installation.

Comment: It just so happens we're also registering a shell icon overlay, which requires writing keys to HKLM, so per user installation is not possible.

Comment: That's a rough design decision OneDrive put you in there then. Pretty poor form. In any case, if you really must do this, then you might consider using something like a bundle to wrap a per-machine and a per-user package into a single installation experience. That way per-user content can still be removed by the users that installed it.

Comment: @Agritite if a bundle seems like a reasonable answer, I can add the additional detail to my answer.